# Google Apps Calendar Resource API in PHP

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I implemented a php application that creates events in google calendar. But i need also to create resources, and i found the documentation for [Google Apps Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/)

My first question is: where can I download the API files. 
And second: i can use this in PHP? Because in the examples that they provide, they use only .NET and Python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This API uses an older Google APIs technology stack called GData. There is a [GData PHP client library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.html) built into the Zend framework, but it doesn't support OAuth2 and doesn't include support for this particular API. You're only option is to construct the OAuth2 tokens, XML body, and HTTP requests yourself using the documentation as a guide.